# In elastic search is a collection queryable while its being added to the index

Tags: nest, elasticsearch

I'm using Nest to insert a list of 60k+ objects into elastic search, specifically calling client.IndexMany(list, indexName).

1. As the list is inserted, is it query-able? or is it only query-able
   after the complete list is indexed?
2. If its the former, is there a way to force it to only be query-able after the list is fully indexed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ad1. The answer is no. Document isn't immediately available for search after indexing.

[Definitive guide](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/near-real-time.html) has really nice chapter why elasticsearch works this way. You should have a look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19963406/refresh-vs-flush) answers for a quick explanation.

Ad2. To refresh your index call `elasticClient.Refresh()`

Hope this helps you.