# Elasticsearch refreshing index automatically with index.refresh=-1?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch with the Java API.

I am indexing offline data with big bulk inserts, so I set `index.refresh=-1`

I don't refresh the index "manually" anywhere.

It seems that refresh *is* done at some point, because queries do return data. The only scenario where the data wasn't returned was when I tested with just a few documents, and querying was done immediately after insertion (using the same `Client` object).

I wonder if index refresh is called implicitly by Elasticsearch or by the Java library at some stage, even when `index.refresh=-1` ?

Or how else could the behavior be explained?

Client generation:

```
Client client = TransportClient.builder().settings(settings)
        .build()
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(address),port));
```

Insertion:

```
BulkRequestBuilder bulkRequest = client.prepareBulk();

for (MyObject object : list) {
    bulkRequest.add(client.prepareIndex(index, type)
            .setSource(XContentFactory.jsonBuilder()
                    .startObject()
                    // ... add object fields here ...
                    .endObject()
            ));
}

BulkResponse bulkResponse = bulkRequest.get();
```

Querying:

```
   QueryBuilder query = ...;

   SearchResponse resp = client.prepareSearch(index)
            .setQuery(query)
            .setSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
            // adding fields here 
            .get();

   SearchHit[] = resp.getHits().getHits();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason the documents were searchable despite refresh interval being disabled could be either due to index-buffer filling up resulting in creation of lucene segment or  translog  being full resulting in commit of lucene segment either of which makes the documents searchable.

As per the documentation

> By default, Elasticsearch uses memory heuristics in order to
>   automatically trigger flush operations as required in order to clear
>   memory.

Also the index buffer settings can be manipulated as follows.

This [article](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/translog.html) is a good read with regard to how data is searchable and durable.

You can also look at this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19963406/refresh-vs-flush) written by one of elasticsearch contributers for more details between `flush vs refresh`.

You can use [indices-stats](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-stats.html) to verify all this i.e verify if there was a flush or refresh

Example :

```
 GET <index_name>/_stats/refresh

 GET <index_name>/_stats/flush
```