# When does ElasticSearch performs a flush

Tags: elasticsearch

**What are the conditions that trigger a flush in ElasticSearch node/index/shard?**

There are good explanations about the flow of ElasticSearch refreshing every second and flushing in a less frequent manner to avoid intensive CPU usage, but which component is responsible to perform the flush?

I tried to look over the source code but didn't manage to find the right place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no fixed interval, Elasticsearch uses some heuristic to determine when to call flush as [mentioned in the official doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-flush.html#flush-api-desc)

> Elasticsearch automatically triggers flushes as needed, using
>   heuristics that trade off the size of the unflushed transaction log
>   against the cost of performing each flush.

Also as explained in [at the end of this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19973721/4039431) from Elastic team member, this heuristic depends on

> depending on how many operations get added to the transaction log, how
>   big they are, and when the last flush happened.

Note: You can also tweak the setting of flush operation but not recommended.

Edit: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/action/bulk/BulkProcessor.java#L48 is the source code which processes the flush operation.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I'm interested in the actual logic of these heuristics, under the assumption they are documented somewhere or al least implemented in ES source code.

Comment: Sure give me sometime will let u know

Comment: @OfekHod, I looked into the Elasticsearch source code and found https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/action/bulk/BulkProcessor.java#L48 if you read the Javadoc of this class (allowing to easily set when to "flush" a new bulk request
 * (either based on number of actions, based on the size, or time))

Comment: @OfekHod, you can find the reference of this bulk processor at multiple places but ultimately flushing is done by a  schedular which calling system can schedule based on three params (actions, size and time). I hope this information gives an answer to your question.

Comment: @OfekHod you can also see  watcher.java in https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/x-pack/plugin/watcher/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/xpack/watcher/Watcher.java#L672 calling this flush operation under close() method.

Comment: @OfekHod thanks for marking it answer and glad I was helpful.